# cocos2d-iphone. Spritesheet depending on a screen resolution?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite, sprite-sheet, suffix-tree, suffix-array

cocos2d adds suffixes to resources by the similar way as "@2x" works for usual iOS apps. I also want to place these pictures into a spritesheet.

The problem is a default cocos2d spritesheet is represented as one png and one plist file with sprite frames.

So how to force the cocos2d engine to apply these suffixes to plist files when it is necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cocos2d suports suffixes for plist files. But if you have "example-hd.plist" then you should use usual frame names inside it (without "-hd" suffix)

Comment: I can't accept an answer for 2 days after posting (this website denies it)